# Separate two paragraph with border

Tags: html, css

Pls hlp me simple problem but very confusing for newbie like me, try hard to break this problem. I was try on desktop and Android but it still get same result.

I have code like this

`

```
<style>
    .box{
        background-color: blue;
        border: 10px solid #000;
        height: 100%;
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:20px;
    }

    .par1{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        margin: 1px;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div class="box">
<div class="par1">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
    </p>
</div>

<div class="par1">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
    </p>
</div>

</div>
```

`

When i run it in browser, the text can't separate into two side. Hlp !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an `<hr/>` element between the paragraphs.

Code:

```
<style>
    .box{
        background-color: blue;
        border: 10px solid #000;
        height: 100%;
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:20px;
    }

    .par1{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        margin: 1px;
    }
```

```
<div class="box">
<div class="par1">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
    </p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="par1">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
    </p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: If he was trying to get a border between to <div>s stacked on top of each other, he would have made them 100% width and not floated. He's clearly trying to get them side-by-side with a border.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/2msLuda6

The boxes are 50% width + 1px margin each side + 1px border each side. So each box is 50% + 4px... That's why it wraps onto a new line.

`box-sizing: border-box;` will include the size of the border in your 50%, and you just need to not use the margin.

Comment: Hey dude, my friend coding that without box-sizing : border-box. And he did it. But here not use margin in par 1 class, and he use two class ( par1 and par2). Here is the code.https://jsfiddle.net/2msLuda6/1/

Comment: Are they supposed to be side by side, or one on top of the other? The fiddle you just linked has the same wrapping problem.... They don't both fit on the same row.

Comment: Side by side dude. I'm sure my friend coding the script like that because i look the tutorial video and it's same code, but the result is different. The different between my code and him is gw using external CSS and on the tutorial the external CSS not recorded.

Comment: Link the tutorial video.

Comment: Wait i Will upload it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14RCLv6KxOHLgdnzrn7Eh2vjV32E16VAP/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1):

```
    .box{
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:20px;
    }

    .par1{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .par1 p { padding:  5px;  border-right:
      1px solid white;
    }

    .par2
    {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .par2 p { padding:  5px; 
      border-left: 1px solid white;
    }


<div class="box">
<div class="par1">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="par2">
    <p>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
    </p>
</div>
```